# How to access custom options of a product in magento from observer event?

Tags: onestepcheckout

For two custom options text fields associated with a product called Location To and Location From, I have set up a Module that has an Observer for checkout_cart_add_product_complete with a method called getLocationCoords, how would I get access to these two fields from the event object that passed to my method.

Answer (score 1):

To Fetch The Custom Option in observer I hope you got the Product Id. If you got the Product Id with the use of below code you can access the particular product custom options.

```
<?php
    $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_ProductId); //product id
    foreach ($product->getOptions() as $_option) {
        $values = $_option->getValues();
        foreach ($values as $data) {
            echo $data->getTitle()."<br/>";

        }
    }
?>
```